# Why can't QNX find filesystem to install to?

Tags: system-installation, qnx

I am trying to install QNX 6 from CD. I formatted the entire hard drive using cfdisk as "QNX 6 filesystem", but I still get the error message "No QNX 6.1 filesystem or greater available to mount".

Any idea how I can fix this error?

Comment: QNX 6 is over 20 years old. R u sure it supports your storage controller?

Comment: My hardware is almost as old. Is there any way to check if it is supported?

Comment: QNX6 is barely functional nowadays, you could test it in a VM instead.

Answer (score 3):

`cfdisk` only operates on the partition table and its partition type codes. It will not actually create any filesystem structures within the partition, especially not for such an obscure/legacy filesystem.

You'll need a separate `mkfs` tool to actually create ("format") the filesystem. Unfortunately I have no idea where such a tool could be found.